# Xcode does not load/install the app to the device

Tags: ios, xcode

I build and run the app on the device. But when I change some code and build and run the app again **it seems that none of my code changes are transferred to the device**. For example `print` statements. However the Xcode status bar says "installing...".

The current workaround is that I delete the app on the device and reinstall.

Does somebody has an idea what is going on and maybe even a solution?

Thank You!

Comment: "The current workaround is that I delete the app on the device and reinstall." Yup, that's certainly one solution. Also try cleaning out the Build Folder before building. Xcode does sometimes get itself stuck in this way. It's just part of life. Quit Xcode, empty Derived Data, restart the computer, try again and see if things are better. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @matt Thank you for your suggestions. I think none of them worked for me (but not with certainty). However I found my solution and I will provide it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think my solution was:

1. Remove developer profile from iOS device
2. Xcode: build and run
3. Trust developer on iOS device
4. Xcode: build and run

---

If this does not work for you I've listed all the actions I've took to get to this point (thanks to @matt's comment):

1. Clean Build Folder
2. Quit Xcode
3. Delete Derived Data
4. Restart Mac/Computer
5. Quit apps on iOS device
6. Restart iOS device
7. (Xcode prompted me to "Install additional components" -> Pressed "Install")
8. Plug in iOS device
9. Xcode: build and run

   - Still not working
10. Delete app on iOS device
11. Xcode: build and run

    - Still not working
12. Remove developer profile from iOS device
13. Xcode: build and run
14. Trust developer on iOS device
15. Xcode: build and run

    - **Works!!!**

Comment: I like this idea of removing the developer profile. It hadn't occurred to me, and it introduces something new into the ever-bubbling stew of dealing with Xcode's unpredictable behaviors. — Now if you could just tell me how to open multiple projects simultaneously without freezing. :)

Answer (score 0):

there is no logical idea for this problems, you can quit `xcode` and then open it again, it works .